# Regex to get all data after certain word and between quotation marks

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

i have an xml file with a lots of data, but it also contains a list of ids which looks like this

```
<test test-id="014727">
<not-test not-test-id="11111">
<not-test not-test-id="22222">
<not-test not-test-id="3333">
<test test-id="019727">
<test test-id="013727">
```

So far I have searched for test-id which gives me a list of all numbers, but it doesn't filter out additional info.

Using a regex in sublime text, how can I get a list of all the numbers after `test-id`?

So from the example above I would have 3 lines of:

1. `014727`
2. `019727`
3. `013727`

Comment: cmd-f, test-id, opt-enter, right-arrow, right-arrow, right-arrow, opt-shift-right-arrow, cmd-c - all numbers have been copied to your clipboard

Comment: Came here to read about inverted commas. Was disappointed to see quotation marks

Comment: @dave excuse my english :-(

Comment: @naomik is it different if i use a mac?

Comment: @dave it is not a duplicate as i have a lot of other info in there that has quotation marks that i wish to ignore

Comment: Do you know how regular expressions work? If so, it's easy as pie. If not, please read up on them, and it'll be easy as pie once you get the hang of it.

Comment: Press `control + H`..you can use as find `^.*?\stest-id="(\d+).*$` and replace with `$1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT

Original question was edited to exclude `<not-test not-test-id="11111">` nodes. Modify step **2** below to add a space () before `test-id` in the search query. The rest of the steps stay the same.

---

> The following keystrokes are for use with Sublime on **OS X**. If someone wants to provide the Windows equivalent, that would be helpful.

1. <kbd>cmd</kbd> - <kbd>f</kbd> to enter search mode
2. type in the text `test-id`
3. press <kbd>opt</kbd> - <kbd>enter</kbd> to match all results in the current file
4. with each instance of `test-id` highlighted, move your cursor right 3 characters with <kbd>→</kbd> **3** times
5. press <kbd>opt</kbd> - <kbd>shift</kbd> - <kbd>→</kbd> to select the entire word (number in this case)
6. press <kbd>cmd</kbd> - <kbd>c</kbd> to copy the selected text to the clipboard
7. move your caret anywhere you wish to paste the copied numbers and press <kbd>cmd</kbd> - <kbd>v</kbd>

[image]

In the gif above, I finish with

1. <kbd>cmd</kbd> - <kbd>a</kbd> to select all text
2. <kbd>cmd</kbd> - <kbd>v</kbd> to paste the copied numbers

Comment: but if there are more than 3 results this will take a lot longer no?

Comment: Unless you have like 10,000 results it should be fine. Even if that's the case, it will still work; it will just be slow yes

Comment: The whole point of doing it this way compared to using a regexp is that it's super quick to try these methods of text navigation/manipulation in sublime. Try it and see!

Comment: This is only going to work if all your IDs have the same number of characters

Comment: @dave nope. That's why I chose `opt`-`shift`-`→` to select the whole word. Each number can be of varying length so long as the length is at least 1.

Answer (score 0):

This regular exp. will search for multiple test-id attribute, and list down the matches globally :

```
/(?:test-id=")([^"]*)(?:")/g
```